Error: This variable has not been assigned a value
I expect this code:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0+ 
#SingleInstance Force

ar := [1, 2, 3]

i := 0
:*:ab:: {
  Loop 3 {
    a := StrCompare(ar[i], "Hi")
    Send(a)
    i++
  }    
}

to work the same with
ar := [1, 2, 3]

:*:ab:: {
  Loop 3 {
    a := StrCompare(ar[A_Index], "Hi")
    Send(a)
  }    
}

That is, the result should be 3 negative numbers. Instead it returns this error:
Error: This variable has not been assigned a value.

Specifically: local i  (same name as a global)

    008: Loop 3
    008: {
▶   009: a := StrCompare(ar[i], "Hi")
    010: Send(a)
    011: i++

What happens? I find this similar question but the answer there doesn't explain why the OP made mistake, so I can't learn anything from it.

It's far from clear what you think this code should do. I assume you're intending that i is an index into the ar array, but you never set that value so AutoHotKey doesn't know what to do. If your loop is intended to iterate over ar then use A_index where you have i. This will address the warning but the code probably won't do anything useful since ar has the values 1,2, and 3, none of which match Hi and send() will just send a series of zeroes.

My bad: strCompare() returns positive, zero or negative integers, not a Boolean true or false. Send() will probably just send a series of negative integers.

#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0+ 
#SingleInstance Force

ar := [1, 2, 3]

i := 0
:*:ab:: {
  global i ; here
  Loop 3 {
    a := StrCompare(ar[i], "Hi")
    Send(a)
    i++
  }    
}

See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Functions.htm#Locals
